# with respect to the usage of tf.summary.scalar

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am studying a Tensorflow implementation, which includes the following code segment. I am not quite understand what does `tf.summary.scalar` try to achieve. My understanding is that `"queue/%s/fraction_of_%d_full" % (q.name + "_" + phase, capacity)` should be a name, but what does this name look like? `math_ops.cast(q.size(), tf.float32) * (1. / capacity)` should be a tensor, but what does this tensor represent?

```
capacity = 50
q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=50, dtypes=dtypes, shapes=shapes)
tf.summary.scalar("queue/%s/fraction_of_%d_full" %
                  (q.name + "_" + phase, capacity),
                  math_ops.cast(q.size(), tf.float32) * (1. / capacity))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [`tf.summary.scalar`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/scalar) call will output the queue size (relative to the capacity) to the tensorboard, as it changes during the session.

The scalar will be visible by the name matching this pattern: `'queue/%s/fraction_of_%d_full'`, e.g. `'queue/fifo_queue_training/fraction_of_100_full'`, where `fifo_queue` is the current queue and its capacity is `100`.

Its value will be equal to the used up space in the queue, i.e. `queue.size() / queue.capacity`. This line is just a fancy way to cast it to 32-bit float:

```
math_ops.cast(q.size(), tf.float32) * (1. / capacity)
```